# "am" or "would"?

Tags: past-tense, auxiliary-verbs

For example, Tom woke up at 5am and say to himself:

> I am not get this up for nothing!

or

> I would not get this up for nothing!

which one is correct or more appropriate?

Comment: What are you trying to say? Do you want to express that he doesn't want to get up?

Comment: @Tlacenka No I want to express the feeling that, Tom get up early and Tom does not want to wast it and wish to work hard!

Comment: Tom doesn't want to get up but wishes to work hard?

Comment: @shin He do want to get up early. And after He got up early, he future encourage himself by saying this sentence.

Comment: I see. Then my answer below "I did not wake up for nothing!" is a correct way to express it. It means that Tom woke up and was very eager to do things, (i.e., He wants to do/accomplish things.) [NOTE: say it in a proper and positive tone. Because if you'll say it while you're angry, it will express your disappointment.]

Comment: Denoising, please allow at least a day or two before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one right away. For info about why this is helpful, please see [“Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)”](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. the correct sentence: "I did not wake up for nothing!"

Since the action is in the past, you use past tense.

Comment: Can I say " I did not wake up this early for nothing!"? I also want to emphasis that he weak up very early.

Comment: Yes. Also note the importance of context when saying this, and do not say it to other people. They may think they made you disappointed.